# Dual-licensing LGPL 2.1 and LGPL 3

Tags: php, licensing, compatibility, lgpl

I maintain a software, a small PHP library, that is released under the LGPL version 3 license (LGPLv3). Someone wants to use the library in their software which has the GPL version 2 license. This license [compatibility matrix](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility) suggests this is not possible without changing the licensing terms of one of the software. I have been requested to dual-license my code under LGPLv2.1 and LGPLv3. Does it make sense, and what might the drawbacks be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The major drawback is that you lose the benefit of the changes made in LGPLv3.  These changes mainly clarify how libraries may be combined with other works.

I would suggest just dual-licensing under LGPLv3 and plain GPLv2.  This will give the other software project what they want, while mostly not giving up the benefits of LGPLv3.

Comment: +1: Sound suggestion IMHO, probably GPLv2+ (version 2 or later) and LGPLv3.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... I have decided to go with GPLv2+ and LGPLv3.